# Is "induction" about inducing or inducting?

Tags: meaning

Earlier today, I realized that I didn't know whether induction was about inducting or inducing, so I decided to look it up.

According to Merriam-Webster, “induction” is [“the act or process of inducting”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/induction).

However, [the page for “induct”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/induct) does not even mention this word, while [the page for “induce”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/induce) gives a definition of induce as “to produce by induction”.

Which is it? The above leads me to believe that it could be both, but in which circumstances is it which?

Comment: You need context to determine which is meant, as is the case with many words.

Comment: I'm not clear whether "usage I've experienced" is a good source for this sort of stuff. But I've come across induction in two uses: i. the process of introducing someone to an organisation or group and ii. in physics.

Comment: Induce is not a scientific term. Induction is and is also, as Att Righ says. To induce is to persuade someone to do something and the noun would be inducing or inducement.

Comment: @Lambie - I think obstetricians consider "induce" to be a scientific term.

Comment: @HotLicks - A scientific term, or just a term of art?

Comment: @JimMack - Isn't a "scientific term" just a term of the scientific arts?

Comment: All is fair in love and war, and mostly, right over the OP's head.

Comment: Induction induces a current in a metal - sounds like a scientific term to a physicist. And an inductor induces an emf

Comment: Induction into the armed forces inducts one. There are multiple kinds of induction, including in domains as far afield as logic and physics (e.g. see @mgb's comment).

Comment: It occurred to me that induce labor is not "scientific". Medicine is an art that is practiced based on science. And "induce" retains the semantic trait of persuade. The pregnant body is "persuaded" to go into labor.

Comment: @Lambie When I add a chemical, called a promoter or inducer, to my culture of recombinant *e. coli* to turn on the gene I slipped in there, the process is called induction, and I **induce** production of a particular gene product. **Scientific term** Example: http://www.nuffieldfoundation.org/practical-biology/gene-induction-%C3%9F-galactosidase-e-coli

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Why are you telling me this? I said that **induce labor** is not "scientific": I never said the word induce cannot be used in other science contexts, did I?

Answer (score 3):

[induct](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/induct) (ODO)

> verb
>   Origin
>   Late Middle English: from Latin induct- ‘led into’, from the verb inducere (see induce).

*Induct* is itself derived from the same source as is *induce*. *Induction* ← *induct* ← *induce*

The meaning of *induction* depends on whether it comes directly from *induce* or via *induct*, which has to be determined from context.

See also: *reduct* (yes, it's a word), *reduce*, *reduction*.

Comment: This doesn't affect the meaning, but "induction" comes from Latin "inductio," which in turn (also) comes from "inducere." (Most English "-tion" words derive from Latin words ending in "-tio, -tionis.")

Answer (score 1):

This may be a British English difference, butI have never heard the word 'inducement' in the context of childbirth. Or indeed in any context. My understanding is that 'induct' is a back-formation from 'induction', that has proved useful and is now used in the context of inducting someone into a new role. Induction can be the act of inducing, or the act of inducting, according to context. The OED confirms that the word 'induce' contains the meaning of the word induct, though the latter is more often used nowadays for clarity.

Comment: You mean British English doesn't use *inducement* in sentences like *His parents offered him cookies as an inducement to finish his project*? This definition is in [British dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inducement).

Comment: Oops — just noticed I should have said *biscuits*, not *cookies*.

Comment: @Peter Shor Though 'bribe' would normally be the natural-sounding choice, 'British English doesn't use _inducement_ in sentences like _His parents offered him a tenner as an inducement to finish his project_' is very misleading. It's principally a register matter, not one of dialect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, *bribe* would probably be more common than *inducement* in the U.S., as well. But when companies are doing similar things, they like to avoid the word *bribe*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, I can't entirely agree. I don't think British medical professionals use _inducement_ in the context of childbirth but I think that's because they just refer to the process using the verb. However I've been aware of "inducements being offered" as a term most of my pretty long life.

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong or preferred?

At the operating room,  you'd hear:

1. It's ok to induce in 5 minutes (start the process of giving anesthesia)
2. We're all set to induce our patient at the operating table. (referring to 'start giving anesthesia' to our patient for surgery)
3. Kindly start induction of anesthesia
4. They're now inducting anesthesia

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The noun **"induction"** can stand alone as a description of a particular process.

In some situations, where the *result* of the process must be observed in order to verify the induction, (labor in childbirth,vomiting) the verb **"induce"** provides a more open-ended description.

Answer (score -2):

"[Induce](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/induce?s=t)" means to bring about or cause.

- The doctor induced labor.

"[Induct](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/induct?s=t)" means to install or introduce and is usually followed by the preposition "into" followed by an indirect object.

- The sergeant inducted me into the Army.

"[Induction](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/induction?s=t)" is generally used as the noun for of "induct," i.e., the act of inducting.  While "induction" can also be the act of inducing, "[inducement](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inducement?s=t)" is generally used as the noun for "induce," i.e., the act of inducing.

Example 1:

"Inducement of labor isn't recommended at this point in your pregnancy."

rather than

"Induction of labor isn't recommended at this point in your pregnancy."

Example 2:

"Elvis' induction into the Army was on March 24, 1958."

rather than

"Elvis' inducement into the Army was on March 24, 1958."

Comment: If you induce a _current_ (by varying a magnetic field), then what is going on is definitely _induction_, not inducement.

Comment: *Induce* has other semantic uses. And so do its derivatives. Cf. comment above, for one.