# Verb for mathematical induction

Tags: word-choice, verbs, mathematics

The development of mathematics unfortunately chose "induction" as a name for a proof technique -- mathematical induction is not inductive, but a kind of *deductive* reasoning! I have seen in numerous mathematical literature that "induce" or "induct" is used as a verb meaning "to do mathematical induction". But the dictionaries I've consulted gave little useful information on this matter. Is using "induce" or "induct" appropriate? Are there better options?

In [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420790/is-induction-about-inducing-or-inducting), the use of "induction" as in "induction of electric current" or "induction of topologies" are discussed. In these cases "induce" seems appropriate.

Comment: If you're asking specifically about usage in mathematics, you might be better asking in one of the math forums, probably https://math.stackexchange.com/, where you're more likely to get an answer that relates to usage by mathematicians and mathematics students.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a mathematics-specific, not an everyday English, usage and certainly belongs on the Mathematics.SE site (they have a terminology tag to cover language usage). This is reflected in the fact that you have found no mention of the usage in standard English dictionaries. In fact, the examples you have found in numerous **sources in the** mathematical literature provides an answer.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I presume you have done math sometime.  You could help out the OP with this, right? Frankly, it's a language question.

Comment: @user405662  That's a disingenuous statement; 'What is the IUPAC name for tertiary butanol' is 'a language question' by that classification, but certainly off-topic on ELU. // Being unfamiliar with a related verb (I've always used 'prove by induction', 'use an inductive process' etc) I'd question why one is felt necessary. But if I had to check usage, I'd be persuaded by examples in the more prestigious articles and textbooks, and wouldn't expect to see this usage mentioned in any dictionary less respected than OED (and it will quite possibly not be there).

Comment: "from this, we may deduce": 108 000 Google hits //  "from this, we may induce": 10 Google hits // "from this, we may induct": 0 Google hits. The latter are not general English usages. This/these usages are in the mathematics domain.

Comment: How would you use the term? Please supply a sample sentence in your question.

Comment: The correct verb form is "induce", but in the specific context of mathematical induction one frequently hears "induct". This does not apply, however, to the rest of mathematics. For example, in representation theory, "induction" refers to "inducing" a representation (from a subgroup to a bigger group), thereby producing an "induced" representation; I've never heard "induct" in the representation-theoretic context.

Comment: I did a couple of years of grad level math and I have no recollection of either induce or induct being used.  "Using induction we can show ... " is the sort of phrasing I recall hearing.  My guess is that, given the more common usage of these words,  my teachers were avoiding what would have sounded odd to both them and me.

Answer (score 1):

It's uncommon to have to require the verb form of *induction* as regards mathematics. However, that doesn't excuse the fact of it being a question suitable for ELU.

As it is, the verb form of *induction* is *induce* (in the sense of *mathematical induction.*)

Per Merriam-Webster,

**induce** means

> to determine by *induction*   **specifically : to infer from particulars**

But as mentioned earlier it's customary to speak in terms of the *noun form*, rather than the *verb form.*

Comment: Talk about a minefield! The full OED has **induce** defn 6. *To **infer**; esp. in recent use, to infer by reasoning from particular facts to general principles; to **derive as an induction**.* But they also have **induct** defn  5. *To form an induction; to **infer by induction**. rare.* As you imply, it should usually be easy enough to sidestep the problem and just talk about ***making** an induction*, rather than ***inducting*** or ***inducing*** anything.